# Function to replace pre_color with post_color using c

Tags: c, function, replace, colors

```
void replace_color(  uint8_t array[], 
             unsigned int cols, 
             unsigned int rows,
             uint8_t pre_color,
             uint8_t post_color )
{
    for (int x = 0; x<(cols*rows); x++)
    {
        if (array[x] == pre_color)
        {
            pre_color == post_color;
        }
    }
    return post_color;
}
```

I created a function to replace every pixel of pre_color to post_color.  I was just wondering, is this function close to being correct?

Comment: `pre_color == post_color;` accomplishes nothing. Your compiler should generate a warning telling you this.

Comment: Yeah interestingly enough, my compiler didn't give me any warning.  It just compiled but when I ran it, it didn't do anything.

Comment: Did you activate warnings? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: The ones from my school.  I'm not sure which one that one is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (array[x] == pre_color)
{
    pre_color == post_color;
}
```

Makes no sense. `pre_color == post_color;` doesn't *do* anything.

You want:

```
if (array[x] == pre_color)
{
    array[x] = post_color;         // set the x'th element of array to post_color
}
```

Also, you can't `return post_color;` in a function that returns `void`. Just delete this line.